# Rails - Active Record Associations with STI & has_many_through in Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, has-many-through

I'm having trouble modeling the data for an application I'm working on. The relevant models are Jobs, Team, Shift, & Employee. I had everything working correctly until I had to split the Drivers and Helpers into Day Drivers, Day Helpers, Custom Drivers, & Custom Helpers. 
Basically, I need some advice and direction about the relationships and their setup because it's beginning to get confusing with the multiple tables with single table inheritance I have setup. 
Basically, I need the `Job` to have a `Team` that is composed of `DayShifts` or `CustomShifts` and be able to assign `Employees` to these different types of `Shifts`. I'm using RailsAdmin to manage the admin, but I think I could work that out if I could just get the model relationships correct. Ideally, on the `Team` admin edit screen I would be able to select the Shift and then have a rails_admin multiple select box for the selected shift's drivers and helpers. So, if I selected `DayShift`, I would get a multiple select for `Day Drivers` and `Day Helpers`.

I feel like I'm missing something or this is totally incorrect and I'm not committed to any of the following setup. I also need to know how I can setup the team to have either a day_shift, night_shift, or other_shift. Any help setting up the model's relationships would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

```
class Employee < AR::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :shift
end

class Driver < Employee
end

class Helper < Employee
end

class Job < AR::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :employees, through: shifts
  has_many :drivers, through: shifts
  has_many :helpers, through: shifts
end

class Team < AR::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :employees
  has_many :drivers
  has_many :helpers
  has_one :day_shift
  has_one :custom_shift
end

class Shift < AR::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :employees
  has_many :drivers
  has_many :helpers
end

class DayShift < Shift
end

class CustomShift < Shift
end
```

Here is the relevant schema:

```
Employee
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "type"
  t.integer  "team_id"
  t.integer  "shift_id"

Team
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "type"

Job
  t.integer "team_id"

Shift
  t.string  "type"
  t.integer "team_id"
```

Comment: Perhaps he separation of ```class Shift``` from ```class CustomShift``` and ```class DayShift``` can be simplified using self joins?

My understanding is that you will want to use self-joins whenever you want to create a hierarchical, “nested” structure. I would argue that your Shift/DayShift/CustomShift is this.

Also not sure whether this type of approach works: 
```class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :day_shift, class_name: "Shift"
      has_one :custom_shift, class_name: "Shift"
    end
```